# Distributing jar containing a library path pointer

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, windows-authentication

I am trying to connect to a MS SQL database using integratedSecurity.

If you do not define a java.library.path to sqljdbc_auth.dll, you will get a: WARNING: Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll cause : no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path

I have tried the standard solution, which is to define a library path: -Djava.library.path=

This works insofar as I can define the library path in Netbeans (project>properties>run>VMOptions) and can access the database when I run from netbeans.

However, I would like to be able to connect to the database outside of Netbeans as well. The aim is to build an executable jar that can be used from different workstations, pointing to a single instance of the DLL on a shared disk.

However when I build and try to execute the jar, it fails.

How do I get the java.library.path pointer to remain the same in the jar as it is in Netbeans (or otherwise enable the jar to use integratedSecurity to connect to the database)?

Comment: You'll need a launcher script or executable that specifies it.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with @Mark - I just tried fiddling with `System.setProperty("java.library.path", ...)` in the Java code itself but it would not fly. Distributing a .bat file with the .jar file would probably be the most straightforward solution.

Comment: I tried the following:
        String path = java.lang.System.getProperty("java.library.path") +<pathToDLL>;
        java.lang.System.setProperty("java.library.path", path"");

When i print out the path, it shows the correct option, but when i deploy, it is still a no-go.